# Placing marker or overlayview on Google Map StreetViewPanorama via lat/long and pitch

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Some web apps (like Nightwalk, seen here: https://nightwalk.withgoogle.com/) have markers placed at various locations in streetviews (notably, above your head).

I know it is possible to place a marker via latitude/longitude, but I am not seeing any option to place a marker as they are in nightwalk (over a users head). If I were to set a marker to a current streetviews latitude/longitude, it would just show up at the photographers foot.

Is a simple way to set a marker taking the pitch/heading into account? Nothing seems to stand out in their API specifications. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

Or are they manually calculating the POV and placing the markers themselves on their own custom layer?

Answer (score -1):

You might to check out the [Overlays with Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) page in Google Maps documentation. Make sure you "Toggle Street View"

The main portion for that demo code will be the following:

```
 panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(astorPlace);
  panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 265,
    pitch: 0
  }));
```